# e.Data.GetData casting problem in WinForms drag-and-drop

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

i'm trying to make a drag-and-drop between 2 instances of my programs, but when i try to cast data to my type it throws an Invalid Cast Exception.

Here is the code:

```
    protected virtual void GetDropIEntities(DragEventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (string s in e.Data.GetFormats())
            Console.WriteLine(s);

        Entity[] myDroppedEnts = (Entity[])e.Data.GetData(e.Data.GetFormats()[0]);

    }
```

The weirdest thing is that Console.WriteLine writes "Entity[]" on the output, but when i try to cast the exception is thrown. Can someone give me a hand with this? Thx in advance!

Comment: DLL Hell is always around the corner when you do this.  Use fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.

Comment: Hello Hans, 
thx for your response but i don't understand how fuslogvw.exe is going to help me to identify the problem. Isn't this tool used to detect missing assemblies?

Comment: It will also show you where the loaded assemblies came from when you select to log all bindings.

Answer (score 1):

To drag and drop objects from one instance of an application to another, the object must be **serializable**.  Otherwise, the cast will not work as expected.

To accomplish this, you can add the `[Serializable]` attribute to your Entity class, and optionally implement the `ISerializable` interface.  For an introduction on how to make a class Serializable, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0(v=VS.90).aspx

This is the same issue with using the Clipboard.  A great example can be seen on this CodeProject site:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/copycustomclasstoclipbrd.aspx