# 'System.InvalidCastException' when Drag and Drop an Object from one Application to another (2 instances of an Application)

Tags: c#, .net

Im about to drag an object (Drag Form with Data) from one Application (client instance A) to another one (client instance B).

Drag and Drop inside the Application works fine.

Here is my Code:

Drag:

```
var dragForms = new List<DragForm<DragFormData>>(dragFormsSource);
myPanel.DoDragDrop(dragForms, DragDropEffects.Move | DragDropEffects.Scroll);
```

Drop:

```
if(myDragEventArgs.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(List<DragForm<DragFormData>>))
{
    Drop(myDragEventArgs.Data); 
}
```

But when I try to Drag and Drop to another client Instance I got:
`System.InvalidCastException` while checking for `GetDataPresent()`.

It's because `myDragEventArgs.Data` is of Type "COM Object" now.

How can I make this work ?

Thanks !

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122987/e-data-getdata-casting-problem-in-winforms-drag-and-drop. You have to use `[Serializable]`

Comment: I still tryed that, but it wasn't working. The Reason was that DragForm uses System.Windows.Forms.Form which isn' t serializable. I just changed the DragEventArgs Data from 'List<DragForm<DragFormData>' to 'List<DragFormData>' which worked fine. Thanks anyway :)